# charles proxy is capturing traffic from a port other than one i've set

Tags: http, http-proxy, charles-proxy

I've set up Charles to capture traffic going through port `8888`. I've set up my mobile device send traffic to that port. It all works peachily.

However, when i browse to a site on my desktop, that traffic is also captured by Charles. As far as i know, traffic on my desktop flows through port `80`. How can i stop Charles from logging traffic from my desktop?

**EDIT:**

I've tried changing the port that Charles listens on and the problem still occurs. Can anyone help me diagnose what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Charles will capture all traffic of devices that use your port 8888 as their proxy, AND of your Windows and Mozilla Firefox traffic by default.

To change this, go to the "Proxy" tab and uncheck "Windows Proxy" (for Windows itself as well as most browsers) and "Mozilla Firefox Proxy".

Cheers

Comment: Right now Charles is capturing traffic from ports other than 8888. Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: Yes - after all, 8888 is the port that your devices use to connect to charles. What Charles is recording, as far as I can tell, is what passes through the port(s) you use by default according to your windows (and firefox) connection settings, which will be 80 for http and 443 for https, unless you've changed it.

This includes the mobile device traffic you route through charles, but also all connections that other applications on your desktop establish.

The only solution I've found to avoid this noise is to manually exclude the most frequent domains, like facebook, google, microsoft.

Comment: Thanks. Im still confused as to why Charles would record traffic coming through a port other than the one ive specified?